# Using str_replace_all() in R to replace the name of some observations in a data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data frame where one of the columns is named after the variable "number" and its values are coded something like "1.times", "2.times", etc. Given that the word "times" is repeated along the whole column, I would like to delete it and just keep the number of times.

In order to do that, I want to use the function `str_replace_all()`.
I have tried the following, though it didn't modify my data frame. Instead, it created a new vector with several values:

`new_data_frame = str_replace_all(original_data_frame$number, "times", "")`

Is there a way I could delete the word "times" from my data frame by using this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't create a new dataframe.

```
original_data_frame$number = str_replace_all(original_data_frame$number, "times", "")
```